# How to Use index.php file for "Blog" Page And this is Not a Home Page

Tags: posts, menus, page-template, homepage

I Created a Page(from Pages -> Add New) Called **"Blog"** when click the **"Blog"** menu in header I want to display the posts from default post not Custom Post Type How to do this ?

Answer (score 2):

What about setting a static page as a page for posts?

`Settings -> Reading -> Front Page displays`

One static page for front (for example Home) and another static page (Blog) for posts.

Comment: "Blog" is not my home page

Comment: I'm telling you to set "Blog" as page for posts and a different page for front.

Answer (score 0):

The following code get you default posts. (make changes accordigly but make sure post_type = 'post')

```
  <?php $args = array(
        'posts_per_page'   => 5,
        'offset'           => 0,
        'category'         => '',
        'category_name'    => '',
        'orderby'          => 'post_date',
        'order'            => 'DESC',
        'include'          => '',
        'exclude'          => '',
        'meta_key'         => '',
        'meta_value'       => '',
        'post_type'        => 'post',
        'post_mime_type'   => '',
        'post_parent'      => '',
        'post_status'      => 'publish',
        'suppress_filters' => true 
    );
    $posts_array = get_posts( $args ); ?>
```

To get this on your Blog page, Save as your page.php as blog.php and use above code (as per theme structure) on the blog.php.